# How Replace Hidden (Strange) Characters From A String With string.Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace, trim

please look at these codes :

```
Health = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Health).Replace("%", string.Empty).Replace("\"", string.Empty).Replace("‭‎",string.Empty).Trim();
File.WriteAllText(@"d:\a.txt", Health);
char[] ar = Health.ToCharArray();
File.WriteAllText(@"d:\a.txt", string.Empty);
foreach (char a in ar)
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"d:\a.txt", a.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}

int a = int.Parse(Health); //-> I Always Have Error In This Line
```

the output of `d:\a.txt` is like :
‎
‭
‭
1
0
0
‬
‬
‎
there are 6 hidden and strange characters in that file and the Length of `ar` array is `9`.
what are those hidden characters and how can i remove them?
why `Trim()` couldn't remove those hidden characters?

Comment: What is the encoding of the file ? Are you sure you are reading the file with the correct encoding ?

Comment: The question you need to answer is "what are these hidden characters"? What did those characters mean?

Comment: thanks for the comments and sry for my delay. which file are you talking about? please take a look at my codes again. the encoding of a.txt file is not important. as i said the length of ar array is 9 instead of 3. i want "100" string without any extra characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you remove the non-printable characters, your `int.Parse` could throw an exception if there are non-numeric characters in the string. You probably want to use `int.TryParse`:

```
int a;
if (!int.TryParse(Health, out a))
{
    // error: non-numeric
}
```

From the looks of things, you're trying to remove everything that isn't a digit (otherwise you wouldn't be doing an `int.Parse` on the result). If that's what you want to do, then you can write:

```
Health = Regex.Replace(Health, "[^0-9]", "");
```

That's probably a bad idea, though, because it would turn `"12foobar34"` into `"1234"`.

You probably should figure out what those bad characters are and how they're getting into your data. Then strip them from the input as soon as possible. Or, better yet, prevent them from getting there in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all non-printables:

```
var str = "kljdfssdflksdfkl\x03kdkddk\x04lkdldök";
var onlyPrintableChars = str.Where(ch => !char.IsControl(ch)).ToArray();
var resultStr = new string(onlyPrintableChars);
```

Comment: I added ascii 3 and ascii 4 to the above test. They are stripped out. Show the ascii codes for the characters that are left in the result str

Comment: are still there, i am so confused! please take a look at that a.txt file -> http://cramit.in/ehvi45jbe6ch

Comment: you never stated that you only required numbers.